# Part of the logo image on my .aspx page, is getting overlapped by a Division; how to bring the logo image on top of everything?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Part of the logo image on my .aspx page is getting overlapped by another image in same Division.
How to bring the logo image on top of everything?
Do I have to set some properties?

Tool: VS2010

Please suggest.

Many Thanks

Comment: Add a z-index via css should do it

Comment: *Division* - is that what *div* means?  I never realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#your_div_id img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

will most likely fix it. Hard to say without seeing any markup

Comment: Thanks,but still having same problem.

Comment: You need to post some HTML. It's impossible to guess what's going on without seeing your code

Comment: In same div,I am having logo & another image(m1).m1 is having upper white part,so that logo behind that should be seen,but logo is overlapped by white part.html code as: " onclick="window.open('Default.aspx', '_top', '');" onmouseover="javascript:menuover(1);" onmouseout="javascript:menuout(1);"> 
Home & css code : .m1 {height:72px; width:100px; float:left; cursor:hand;cursor:pointer; border-bottom:solid 1px #076aad; text-align:center; font:13px/1 arial; background-image:url('images/m1.gif'); color:#e03819; text-shadow: 1 1 1 #076bae; position:relative; z-index:1;

} So please suggest.Thanks.